# how to add same view in different layout in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to add one view in different linear layout ..
Here is my code::

EditProfileActivity::

```
LinearLayout editPageLayout;
LinearLayout editPageLayoutsave;

public void initViews() {

    editPageLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutForEdit);
    editPageLayoutsave=(LinearLayout)  findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutForSave);
}


            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                Field field = fieldValuesArray.get(i);
                count = count + 1;
                int lastCoreFieldId = count++;
                Log.i("TextviewID",""+textviewid);

                View view1 = runTimeUiLibs.getRuntimeViewtext(field,
                        lastCoreFieldId,textviewid);
                if (view1 != null) {
                    LinearLayout fieldAndPrivacyLayout = UtilityClass
                             .getLinearLayoutHorizontal(EditProfileActivity.this);

                    view1.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsBasic);
                    layoutParamsBasic.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                    fieldAndPrivacyLayout.addView(view1);

                   editPageLayout.addView(fieldAndPrivacyLayout);
                }

                View view = runTimeUiLibs.getRuntimeView(field,
                        lastCoreFieldId,textviewid);
                textviewid++;
                if (view != null) {
                    LinearLayout fieldAndPrivacyLayout = UtilityClass
                            .getLinearLayoutHorizontal(EditProfileActivity.this);

                    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsBasic);
                    layoutParamsBasic.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                    fieldAndPrivacyLayout.addView(view);
                    **editPageLayoutsave.addView(fieldAndPrivacyLayout);** //Here I got error that I cant use same view in different layout(to add runtimeView())
                    **editPageLayout.addView(fieldAndPrivacyLayout);**//If I   remove this then I am getting output as shown in image

                }
                fieldMapList.put(String.valueOf(view.getId()), field);
            }
        }
```

Here is my xml File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/bg_light1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:id="@+id/edt_ll">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutForEdit"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutForSave"
            android:orientation="vertical">



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_yma" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I am creating one dynamic form which is generating from json file..In this, I have one layout which has Textview only and in second layout, different fields(EditText,Spinner,RadioGroup,Ratingbar) are generating...and I want of that selected (choosen) values and to save in database...

Right now getting this output:
[image]

I want output like :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create your `your_layout_file_to_resuse.xml` and use `include` tag for resuse the tag

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”match_parent”
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/your_layout_file_to_resuse"/>

  .....
</LinearLayout>
```

see this link [Re-Useing Layout](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Comment: In my case, What should I write in include layout=??...Please tell me..Thanx in advance

Comment: what is common in your layout , that can placed in your `include` layout

Comment: I write   <include layout="linearLayoutForEdit"/> but this didn't work

Comment: yea..I read..and I write  <include layout="@layout/edit_profile_save"/> but still getting same output which i got early